# Unsplash.com: How can I get the username from a preselected photo ID via the Unsplash API

Tags: python

I have a list of manually selected [Unsplash](https://Unsplash.com) photo IDs that I want to display on a website. Now I want to make sure to print out proper attribution via the Unsplash API.

The .get_attribution function in [PyUnsplash](https://pythonhosted.org/pyunsplash/) is perfect for my use case. However, it requires a username or search query to return the attribution.

I was hoping to simply query the API with the photo ID, but sadly, that does not work.
So if there's any suggestions how to get from photo-ID to username via the API, I would love to hear them.

_

*Alternative question titles:
Get Unsplash user’s profile by photo id*

Answer (score 0):

[github.com/salvoventura/](https://github.com/salvoventura/) released a new version of PyUnsplash. Now this is possible.

> PyUnsplash v1.0.0rc1 (release candidate, v1)
>
> This is the first release candidate for production ready 1.0.0 of
>   PyUnsplash. Thanks to all the early adopters, there have been a number
>   of improvements and bugfixes and now should be a good time to start
>   the rc process.
>
> This release brings one useful addition:
>
> Introduction of SinglePhoto which allows instantiating a Photo object
>   using a photo_id Deprecated format value 'str' in favor of 'txt' in
>   get_attribution()

Answer (score 0):

I just did some troubleshooting for unsplash queries with Paw to a `photos/:id` endpoint. Using the requests library I was able to pull the username out of the returned json object:

```
import requests


def send_request():
    # Request
    # GET https://api.unsplash.com/photos/4Fjjyhg1YFc

    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url="https://api.unsplash.com/photos/4Fjjyhg1YFc",
            params={
                "client_id": "YOUR_API_KEY",
            },
            headers={
                "Cookie": "",
            },
        )

        data = response.json()
        print('Response HTTP Status Code: {status_code}'.format(
            status_code=response.status_code))
        print('Unsplash API Username: {uname}'.format(
            uname=data['user']['username']))
        print('Unsplash API Full Name: {fname}'.format(
            fname=data['user']['name']))
        print('Unsplash API Location: {location}'.format(
            location=data['user']['location']))
        print('Unsplash API Portfolio: {portfolio}'.format(
            portfolio=data['user']['portfolio_url']))
        print('Unsplash API Instagram: {ig}'.format(
            ig=data['user']['instagram_username']))
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        print('HTTP Request failed')

send_request()
```

For more info, checkout the 'Response' section under [Get A Photo](https://unsplash.com/documentation#get-a-photo) in the docs. It shows all the fields returned, you may find more you'd like to use.